# xsltproc very slow processing HTML piped through tidy

Tags: xml, tidy, xslt

I'm using xsltproc to fix HTML files that have been converted to well-formed XML using tidy, but the run-time is unbelievable bad, upwards of a minute for each file.  I'm wondering if the XML output by tidy is a problem, or my xsl is stupid, though it's pretty damn simple:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('php')"></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @user477399: Do those input documents have a proper DOCTYPE declaration? Is the xml parser trying to retrieve the external DTD or even performing validation?

Comment: This is *not* a XSLT question per se, probably just an XML parsing problem.

Comment: Validation!  That seemed to fix the problem when I turned off validation.  Awesome.

Comment: Note, however, that it's almost certainly not validation itself that was taking the time:  W3C serves copies of DTDs and schema very slowly as a way of encouraging people to install local caches for material like DTDs and schemas that change very seldom, rather than hitting the W3C server every time.  See http://www.w3.org/Help/Webmaster.html#slowdtd for more info.